# Generate a page based on an autocomplete result from a text box (Flask/Python backend)

Tags: python, html, text, routes, flask

I've got a text box which is being filled with an autocomplete result

```
$("#job_names").autocomplete({source : data});

//later on in the html

<input id="job_names" type= "text"/>
<input type= "submit" value= "Search" id= "search"/>
```

On my  python/flask backend, I've got something like this.

```
@app.route('/jobs/<job_name>')
def display_job_info(job_name= None):
    #does stuff with the autocomplete result
    #here, job_name is the autocomplete result
```

I can explain more if desired, but can someone show me how to take something from an html  tag, and pass it off to my python backend through the url/route?

Comment: If it would make things simpler, I want to take the autocomplete result and generate a page with it, if that makes sense.

Comment: figured it out with this, if anyone is interested.
http://askville.amazon.com/Javascript-Input-launch-HTML/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=1807874